# Coldfusion Date without slash

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-7

I'm trying to enter dates without slashes, for example 09092013. 
Is there a quick and easy way to convert those strings into date objects? 
ParseDateTime() didn't like it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean other than using `left()` to get the first two, `mid()` the second two, and `right()` the last four, then using those as inputs into `createDate()`? how much quicker and easier are you wanting to get?

Comment: simple enough ;-) Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You could use Java

```
formatter = CreateObject("java", "java.text.SimpleDateFormat").init('MMDDYYYY)';
formattedDate = formatter.parse(yourDate);
```

Comment: Yes, yes and YES! Java is a much nicer way to do this than manually stripping out the date values using left, mid and right..in my opinion.